# (Java/Groovy) How to assign case to the results I got from two different queries?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm hoping to assign a Workflow case to both the finance users (financeusers) and the msml user (msmluser). How do I join the query results together as one list so that I can put it in () of the assign case line: currentCase.setAssignees( );

My scripts for the finance users & msml user (separate) are as followed.
Please help me combine them!

//Assign finance users-----------------------------------------------------------------

//Get list of finance users

```
java.util.List financeUsers = resp.findUsers(" eq 'department', 'pro_services' ");

out << "\nMnS Ops: " + financeUsers.size()

if(financeUsers==null || financeUsers.size()==0) {

resp.fail('The list of users in MnS Ops department could not be found. Please contact     your administrator.');

 }
```

//Set finance users as assignees on the current case

```
currentCase.setAssignees(financeUsers);

resp.update(currentCase);
```

//Assign MSML User-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def cc = currentCase;
def creUser = currentCase.getCreatedBy();
```

//Get the CRE employeeId
    def creId = creUser.getCustomField('employee_id').getValue();

//Get the MSML for the current CRE

```
def query = "SELECT MSML_NUMBER FROM CRE_PROFILES WHERE CRE_NUMBER='" + creId + "'";

def entry = resp.customTableFindFirst(query);

def msmlId = entry.MSML_NUMBER;

java.util.List users = resp.findUsers(" eq 'employee_id', '" + msmlId + "'");

if(users==null || users.size()==0) {
resp.fail('The MSML could not be found. Please contact your administrator.');
}

def msmlUser = users.get(0);

cc.setAssignee(msmlUser);
resp.update(cc);
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having? The question is quite hard to follow. Maybe if you could come up with a simple example showing the issue rather than loads of disjointed untestable code?

Comment: Are you asking how to join two lists together?  It's really unclear.  If so, you might look into the `addAll` method.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to join the two query results together as one entity so that I can plug it in the set assignee line: cc.setAssignee();